# angular akita very strange behavior

Tags: angular, akita

Here I am getting data from storage

```
sendRequest() {
    this.userservise.getAllUsers(...)
    console.log("bedore")
    this.query.selectAll().subscribe(users => {
        console.log("inside")
        this.users = users
    })
    console.log("after")
}
```

Here I write them in storage

```
  getAllUsers(...) {
    var url = ...
    return this.http.get<User[]>(url, { withCredentials: true }).subscribe(u => {
      this.store.set(u)
    });
  }
```

The strange behavior is that the "insede" function fires many times, with one more time on each new request. look
[scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjEcP.png)

The query to the database is always sent one, as it should be.
Also, if you exclude the Akita, everything will work fine.

```
  sendRequest() {
    this.userservise.getAllUsers(...).subscribe(users => {
        this.users = users
      })
  }

  getAllUsers(...): Observable<User[]> {
    var url = ...
    return this.http.get<User[]>(url, { withCredentials: true })
  }
```

Store:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { EntityState, EntityStore, StoreConfig } from '@datorama/akita';
import { User } from '../user';

export interface TodosState extends EntityState<User, number> { }

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
@StoreConfig({ name: 'todos' })
export class TodosStore extends EntityStore<TodosState> {
  constructor() {
    super() ;
  }
}
```

Query:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { QueryEntity } from "@datorama/akita";
import { TodosState, TodosStore } from "./store";
    
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TodosQuery extends QueryEntity<TodosState> {
    constructor(protected override store: TodosStore) {
        super(store);
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you change your getAllUsers() function to as follows:

getAllUsers(...) {
    var url = ...
    return this.http.get<User[]>(url, { withCredentials: true }).pipe(tap(u => {
      this.store.set(u)
    }));
  }

Comment: @HaseebAhmed This only works if I subscribe to the getAllUsers method. If you try q.selectAll().subscribe then it doesn't even initiate sending the request. But it will probably be right, my double-subscription syntaxis is wrong i think

Comment: I think I might have an idea what might be going wrong. I'll get back to you in a little bit.

Comment: Can you please check my implementation at (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ux5gfg)? I think you're using RxJS observable in some odd manner which might be causing this. I can't tell what's wrong until I have a look at the complete code but maybe my example will help you understand the appropriate way of doing it.

Comment: @HaseebAhmed Hello! If i just use todos$ in html, then it works fine, but it's not convenient to work with Observable because you can't use *ngIf and access fields. And if i try `this.todos$.subscribe(u => { this.users = u; console.log(1);});` then the situation is the same.

Comment: Sorry @Tidus213 but you're wrong about that. using observable direct in the HTML is very beneficial and you can things like the following: on some parent, do the following "*ngIf="todos$ | async as todos"" and you can do something like this then: "{{ todos.length }}" and "{{ todos | json }}".

Comment: @HaseebAhmed I read about it, indeed, using async directly in the template instead of subscribing seems like a good pattern. Of course it is interesting why in my example there was such behavior, but I will consider that it is simply absolutely wrong. Thank you =)

Comment: I'll be sharing my suggestion as an answer below. Please accept it :-D
I'll also make an example of how you were trying to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a few things wrong with what you're doing. I think you're using RxJS observable in some odd manner which might be causing this. I can't tell what's wrong until I have a look at the complete code but maybe my example will help you understand the appropriate way of doing it.

In your service, you should have a getUsers method as follows:

```
public getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    var url = "";
    return this.http.get<User[]>(url).pipe(tap((data) => {
        this._store.add(data);
    }));
}
```

Then in your component.ts file, do the follows:

```
public readonly todos$ = this._query.selectAll();
```

And finally, in the HTML template, you can use it as follows:

```
<ol>
  <li *ngFor="let user of todos$ | async">
    {{ user.name }}
  </li>
</ol>
```

Incase you want to access properties of the User[], you can do it as follows in the HTML:

```
<p *ngIf="todos$ | async as todos">
    You have: {{ todos.length }}. <br />
    JSON: {{ todos | json }}
</p>
```

You can also see a running example of the above on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ux5gfg).

Update:

I think I also realized, what you're doing wrong. Below is the example that you shared in OP.

```
sendRequest() {
    this.userservise.getAllUsers(...)
    console.log("bedore")
    this.query.selectAll().subscribe(users => {
        console.log("inside")
        this.users = users
    })
    console.log("after")
}
```

The reason why you're getting inside one more time than the last time, every time is because you're subscribing to a new observable every time without discarding the old one. Your problem can be fixed as follows but it still won't be a recommended approach.

```
sendRequest() {
    this.userservise.getAllUsers(...)
    console.log("bedore")
    this.query.selectAll()
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(users => {
        console.log("inside")
        this.users = users
    })
    console.log("after")
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but your version does not work in this form, the request is simply not sent. i used subcribe instead of pipe in getUsers()

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you're saying doesn't work?

Comment: the request is simply not outdated, that is, it is not sent to the backend server